# Different SESSION_COOKIE_AGE setting for different users

Tags: python, django, django-settings, django-sessions

Im executing session timeout in django with these settings:

```
SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST = True
SESSION_COOKIE_AGE = 600
```

is very easy, i'm looking for a way to differ the session cookie age for user group. In example, i want to timeout a regular user much faster then a staff member or even admin. Is there any easy way to modify session cookie age on the fly, via middleware or in view? Is there a way to avoid writing new session menagement?

Answer (score 3):

This is what I did on my project:
I used a `user_logged_in` signal in my `admin.py`
and set `SESSION_COOKIE_AGE` from there. I'm not sure if this is a good approach though but it works.

```
from django.contrib.auth.signals import user_logged_in

def login_hook(sender, **kwargs):
    settings.SESSION_COOKIE_AGE = settings.SESSION_COOKIE_AGE_ADMIN

user_logged_in.connect(login_hook)
```

you can also try `session.set_expiry` function if applicable.

Comment: it's a valid answer for regular users but I can update my cookies as a slightly more educated user. do you know a way to handle that scenario? I thought I can add a custom value to session and write a custom middleware to check that variable instead of depending cookie. What do you think guys?